# Run part of a method under spring transaction

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a method that does something like this

```
class EmployeeService {
  @Transactional
  public void perform() {
    // perform DB operations()
    createEmployee()
    // call some async service that relies on the persisted data
    runEmployeeBGV();
  }
}
```

`runEmployeeBGV()` crates a separate thread which does bgv operations.

I want data to be persisted as soon as the `createEmployee()` method ends. But due to limitations on @Transactional(and my knowldge), I am not sure on how to exclude `runEmployeeBGV()` out of the scope of transaction.

Please note that these two operations need to reside within `perform()` method which is being called by another service class where `EmployeeService` is injected.

Is there any way we can achieve this without calling these methods separately from the client code?

Answer (score 1):

You can move those methods to another service and move `@Transaction` to `createEmployee()`

something like that

```
class EmployeeService {

  private EmployeeRepo repo;
  private EmployeeBGV bgv;

  public void perform() {
    repo.createEmployee()
    bgv.runEmployeeBGV();
  }
}

class EmployeeRepo {
    @Transactional
    public void perform() {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @lukwas. However, I was hoping if there is any other way than extracting it to a different service.

Comment: You could use, TransactionSynchronizationManager to run second method after commit of first, but I think separating is cleaner